# SSIS Export to CSV but start to write at line 3

Tags: ssis-2012

I've tried googling for an answer but have had no luck. 
What I need to do is write to a csv file that has a double header row. The columns I need as headers are in row 2 and I can set them using 'Header rows to skip'.
However, I need to start writing data at line 3 and this isn't currently happening.
What's happening is that the header in row 1 is being removed.
Everything else is fine with the package.

Any ideas ?

Comment: My first thought was to trick the Flat File Connection to use `{CR}{LF}{CR}{LF}` as the header row delimiter but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Yeah it's a tricky one - my other thought is to add a script to replace the header row with the first two lines of the template but it seems a bit clunky.

Answer (score 0):

You can trick your Flat File Target into producing the desired output if you can do without the comfort of automatically creating the column header names from your pipeline metadata:

On your Flat File Connection, uncheck the option *"Column names in the first data row"*

Open your Flat File Target *"Advanced Editor"* and switch to the `Component Properties` tab.

Find the `Header` property under `Custom Properties` and edit the text to contain the desired header data ending with `\r\n\r\n` to produce the desired blank line between your head line and your data.

Setting `Header` to

```
column1;column2\r\n\r\n`
```

your resulting file should look something like this:

`column1;column2`<kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>
<kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>
`val11;val12`<kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>
`val21,val22`<kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>